# Get AD User with Multiple Where Conditions

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a small script to display all users who user accounts are currently marked as enabled and haven't logged in over 365 days ago.

I currently have:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * | where{($_.Enabled -eq $False -And $_.LastLogonDate -eq (Get-Date).AddDays(-365))}
```

A scenario in which I might use this is to check that IT staff have been marking user accounts as disabled when employees have left the company.

But this isn't working - it's just returning nothing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You say you want _enabled_ users, but your code is looking for _disabled_ ones. Also, your date condition should e `-le`, not `-eq`

Comment: My apologies.  The "enabled -eq $False" is me being next to entirely useless. I was trying to figure it out before I posted and forgot to revert to what I had originally before copying. However, after changing -eq to -le it seems to be working now. Thanks.

Out of curiosity, what is the -le?

Comment: `-le` is less than or equal to. Check out [comparison operators doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6)

Comment: @ReeceAlqotaibi: jkdba answered your `-le` question; given that your question is unlikely to be of benefit to future readers, can I suggest you delete it?

Answer (score 0):

Your statement searched for accounts that are disabled and last logged in one year ago. If you want accounts that last logged in more than a year ago, change that `-eq` to a `-lt`:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * | where { $_.Enabled -eq $true -And $_.LastLogonDate -lt $(Get-Date).AddDays(-365) }
```

Comment: OP wanted enabled accounts see comments on question.

Comment: Also, the question at hand qualifies for the following standard closure reason: "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers." Such questions are better addressed with _comments_ (as were given here), whereupon the question can be closed or deleted.